# Taxes not updated after manually adding a product to an order. Drupal Commerce

Tags: commerce

Using [Commerce 7.x-1.10](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce).

I created several tax rules to fit different countries. All of them works fine through the checkout process.

The problem is that if I (as admin user) manually add a product Line Item to the order at: `admin/commerce/orders/ORDER-ID/edit`, then the taxes are no re-calculated.

I already enabled the option: `Enable the local action link on order edit forms to apply pricing rules.` in this admin page: `admin/commerce/config/order`. Loop my capture bellow. I expected to see a link in the edit order form, but I see no link there. What's the goal of this feature??

```
To reproduce:
1) an order is created
2) as admin user I go to `admin/commerce/orders/ORDER-ID/edit`
3) add a new product to the order
4) save
5) the taxes are not re-calculated
```

**UPDATE 2**: changing the order status didn't work for me: https://www.drupal.org/node/1094266#comment-4269794, https://drupalcommerce.org/questions/4302/rules-not-firing-during-admin-order-editing
[image]

Answer (score 1):

We ran into the same issue which we worked around by using the [Drupal Commerce Point of Sale module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pos) to manage manual orders.

As of now, the button "apply pricing rules" is working for us in the order editing form to apply the taxes but we found it easier to use Commerce POS. Your mileage may vary...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Funny thing is you will need a little patch, which I provided, in order to show taxes in Commerce POS :
https://www.drupal.org/node/2097597